# angular 2.0.0-rc.1 + karma: provide Router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When a test needs an instance of the `Router`, just providing `Router` itself is not enough:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

import {it, inject, beforeEachProviders} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {ComponentToTest} from './component.to.test';

describe('ComponentToTest', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    Router,    
    ComponentToTest
  ]);


  it('should call getData() on contruct', inject([Router], (router) => {
    spyOn(ComponentToTest.prototype, 'getData');
    expect(ComponentToTest.prototype.getData).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    let component = new ComponentToTest(router);
    expect(ComponentToTest.prototype.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

Following error will occur:

> Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Router'(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Router' is decorated with Injectable.

Yet I don't really know how to resolve the router.

## `Router` parameters

#### _rootComponent: Object,

#### _rootComponentType: Type,

In alpha we had the `RootRouter`:
`import {RootRouter} from 'angular2/src/router/router';`. This is gone now without any replacement.

#### _componentResolver: ComponentResolver,

#### _urlSerializer: RouterUrlSerializer,

Haven't got a clue on how to provide these.

#### _routerOutletMap: RouterOutletMap,

Seems like this one is already provided in the Router itself

#### _location: Location

This parameter can possibly still be provided by `SpyLocation`:

```
import {SpyLocation} from '@angular/common/testing';

describe('ComponentToTest', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    provide(Location, { useClass: SpyLocation }),
  ]);
});
```

Comment: So, my answer actually solved your problem? Or did just the bounty period expire?

Comment: I assumed giving the bounty would automatically mean you solved the issue.. anyway I bumped into another semi-related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37147812/angular-2-0-0-rc-1-karma-provide-routesegment

Comment: Also for some reason the current api reference (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/) does not mention ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS

Comment: It was added very recently and the Angular team was busy with preparing and attending ng-conf. They will fix this soon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Import `@angular/router/testing` and provide `ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS` in `beforeEachProviders()`

```
beforeEachProviders(() => [
  ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS,
  ComponentToTest
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use `import {RouterTestingModule} from '@angular/router/testing';` and to add `RouterTestingModule` to your imports in your test file.

```ts
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule
    ]
  });
  TestBed.compileComponents();
});
```

Comment: The RouterTestingModule exists since Angular 2.0.0-rc.5, before it was called RouterTestModule

Comment: I'm not sure if RouterTestModule exists on rc.1