# angular 2.0.0-rc.1 + karma: provide RouteSegment

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When a component is injected with RouteSegment, just providing the RouteSegment in the test is not enough:

component.ts:

```
export class ComponentToTest {
  private param: string;

  constructor(routeSegment: RouteSegment) {
    this.param = routeSegment.getParam('param');
    this.getData();
  }
}
```

component.spec.ts:

```
import {Router, RouteSegment} from '@angular/router';

import {it, inject, beforeEachProviders} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router/testing';

import {ComponentToTest} from './component';

describe('ComponentToTest', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    ROUTER_FAKE_PROVIDERS,
    RouteSegment,
    ComponentToTest
  ]);

  it('should call getData() on contruct', inject([Router], (router) => {
    spyOn(ComponentToTest.prototype, 'getData');
    expect(ComponentToTest.prototype.getData).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    let component = new ComponentToTest(router);
    expect(ComponentToTest.prototype.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

Following error will occur:

> Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteSegment'(?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or
>   have valid type annotations and that 'RouteSegment' is decorated with
>   Injectable.

I have no idea on how to provide the RouteSegment parameters.

Comment: Seems to work here https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/107016ec124490969484327f0016158190be94a3/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/test/testing_public_browser_spec.ts I suspect the problem in `ComponentToTest`

Comment: Apologies, I didn't mention that the ComponentToTest injects RouteSegment.

Comment: Injecting `RouteSegment` works when you run the application (instead of the test)?

Comment: Yes it does, I get the error in several test files but my application builds and runs without issues.

Comment: Does it help when you add `provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: App}),` to `beforeEachProviders()`?

Comment: I've added it but no success. The error still appears.

Comment: Has there beed any more progress on this issue, I'm having the same problem. Since we migrated to rc1 we had to change routeParams to routeSegment and our tests are failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1

[See the answer of HomeBrew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37314011/531122)

Didn't work for me, still not sure why.

## Solution 2

A mock implementation of RouteSegment:

```
class MockRouteSegment implements RouteSegment {
  urlSegments: any;
  parameters: any;
  outlet: string;
  _type: any;
  _componentFactory: any;
  type: any;
  stringifiedUrlSegments: string;
  constructor(parameters?: { [key: string]: any; }) {
    this.parameters = parameters
  }
  getParam(param: string) {
    return this.parameters[param];
  }
}
```

Provide it like this:

```
provide(RouteSegment, { useValue: new MockRouteSegment({ 'key': 'value' }) })
```

Comment: I feel that something weird is at play here because I do use getParam in my component and the solution I found works. Hopefully this is just an issue in the angular code and will be fixed eventually, creating a mock RouteSegment for testing shouldn't be a long term solution as it's such a pain to do each time.

Comment: I actually tested both in my setup, with and without the getParam function, it respectively failed and passed, so yea I also don't know what's going on. It is indeed better to not use Mock components, however this is not the first time I needed to do this ([#8303](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8303#issuecomment-215545372)), I now group them in a testing module, not a lot of duplication then..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I had to look at the angular router code and the specs they have in there repo. You should be able to provide the routeSegment like this:

```
import {RouteSegment, Router} from '@angular/router';
provide(RouteSegment, {useFactory: (r: any) => r.routeTree.root, deps: [Router]})
```

or you can just mock out a new RouteSegment similar to how you did with RouteParams:

```
provide(RouteParams, { useValue: new RouteParams({ page: 'terms-conditions' }) }),
```

Is now this:

```
provide(RouteSegment, { useValue: new RouteSegment([], { page: 'terms-conditions' }, null, null, null) }),
```

To create it you just have to pass it a couple of extra parameters.

Comment: When I try to use it in a test _instantiateProvider fails, when the component itself uses the routeSegment in a test I get the `TypeError: undefined is not an object` error.

Comment: Hmm.... my components also use the route segment and it works fine. I'm wondering if it's something do to with the way you create your test. I never 'new' my component as you are in the test you showed. I just inject the component as you have the router. In your case above you could inject the component and remove the router injection completely. I would also recommend moving the getData() call to the ngOnInit, it's very difficult to test this type of thing in the constructor.

Comment: Other tests who just inject ComponentToTest, fail similarly. In the example I only inject the Router into ComponentToTest, in that case your solution works. However in the tests I performed I also injected a service that uses the function getParam. It seems like the RouteSegment of your solution cannot handle actual use of RouteSegment functionality.